# XML elements in new line in VB.net

Tags: xml

I am using XMLTextWriter in my VB.net file to build XML file.
How do I make sure that the writer writes the elements in new line. As I am building XML file based on values from the database it sometimes will build xml for 100 or more records and some elements are breaking up and appearing in two lines.

How do I make sure that it writes xml elements in new lines always.

```
Dim memory_stream As New MemoryStream()
    Dim settings As XmlWriterSettings = New XmlWriterSettings()
    settings.Indent = True
    settings.NewLineOnAttributes = True
    settings.Encoding = UTF8Encoding.Default



    Dim xml_text_writer As XmlWriter

    xml_text_writer = XmlWriter.Create(memory_stream, settings)
```

Comment: Why do you care? Xml parsers don't.

Comment: what do you mean by "and some elements are breaking up and appearing in two lines." ?

Comment: You might add an example of how your XML is formatted compared to how you would like it formatted so people can help get the correct settings.  But Peter's answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500618/xml-elements-in-new-line-in-vb-net/1554035#1554035 is where you should probably start looking.

Answer (score 2):

Does the indent setting do this? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.indent.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to ahve your elements on a new line